# How can I set the font style of a hyperlink?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

When using LibreOffice on a mac, I can only set the cell font style of a hyperlink that has been visited (opened in a browser). I cannot set the font style of a cell that has an 'unvisited' hyperlink.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are different options, depending on your needs. You could use a custom cell style only for cells containing hyperlinks, but you will have to assign that style manually or using a macro.

Another way would be to use Conditional Formatting. With conditional formatting, you could check either for the cell text starting with "http", for example (using the [LEFT](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_LEFT_function) function). But this works only if you're using the URL as link text.

Another approach would be to insert hyperlinks using the [HYPERLINK](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_HYPERLINK_function) function. This way, you could use conditional formatting again, checking if the current cell contains the [HYPERLINK](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_HYPERLINK_function) function with the help of the [FORMULA](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_FORMULA_function) function.

All those approaches aren't really straightforward, but they may work as a workaround.